# CSS - Is it possible to maintain header properties even if it's got a fixed position

Tags: html, css

Here's a simple table code.

Here's is the jsfiddle code for it - [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/0m4hdf0p/1/)

The thing is that when the `head` gets a `position : fixed` it simply lose all the properties of the `table-` such as the whole width, each cell width.

So the thing I would be happy to know is if there's any way to fix it?

Thanks for any kind of help

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    
        <style>
            table {
            width: 100%;
            }
    
            th td {
             width:25%;
            }
    
            thead {
            background-color: #f00;
            position: fixed;
            }
    
        </style>
    
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>1</th>
                    <th>2</th>
                    <th>3</th>
                    <th>4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
    
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
    
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>A</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                    <td>C</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
    
    
            </tbody>
    
        </table>
    
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why don't you add a js fiddle

Comment: May I ask you what you want to achieve?

Comment: @GibboK he wants it to be same as the table header without a positon:fixed

Comment: Well I would like to the header will have a positon:fixed but also that it will still be above the right column

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the following css

```
thead > tr> th {width: 330px;}
```

If the position is fixed it gets auto width, if you set width for the th then it seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Update css

```css
        table {
        width: 100%;
        }

        th td {
         width:25%;
        }

        thead {
        background-color: #f00;
        position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
        }
thead th{width: 2000px}
```